# Кнопка подробнее

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемые специалисты.

У меня такой вопрос. Я делаю постраничный вывод сообщений из базы данных. Ничего особого. Название сообщения, дата публикации, краткий текст и полный текст. Проблемы особой у меня не было, пока не дошел до того момента, когда мне нужно было сделать так, что бы каждое сообщение можно было открыть в отдельном окне, нажав по кнопке подробнее. 
В БД есть `id` всех сообщений. Подскажите, как это реализовать. То есть какой код мне нужно написать в кнопке подробнее и как передать `id` на страницу для отображения полного текста сообщения.

З.Ы. У меня получилось сделать переход на страницу, но в любом случае у меня отображается 1 сообщение. Как передать `id` в страницу отображения полного сообщения.

Заранее большое спасибо за советы.

Comment: типа так :

    page.php
    <table>// !! у меня представление в виде таблицы !!
    <?$query = "select * from messages";//берем все сообщений
    $res = mysql_query($query);?>
    <?while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)):?>
    <tr><td><a href="podrobnee.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>"> Subject:<?=$row['tema_message']?></a></td></tr>
    <?endwhile;?>
    </table>
Теперь файл podrobnee.php должен отрабатыват наш запрос:

    // здесь код, точно как написал @Node-pro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день. Можно передать сообщение методом GET. Пример ссылки будет mail.php?id=xx. Реализовать скрипт какой выводит полное сообщение, можно примерно так:

```
<?php $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `avtor`, `subj`, `text` FROM `mail` WHERE `id` = ".$id));
echo "Тема: ".$a['subj']."<br/> Автор: ".$a['avtor']." <br/><hr/> ".$a['text'].";
?>
```

Писал код быстро, не пинать =)

Comment: Это только пример!

Comment: насколько я понимаю, в вашем варианте тема будет являться ссылкой на полный пост, так?

Comment: Верно, если Вам надо помощь могу написать свои контакты

Answer (score 0):

Методом get передавать ID сообщения и отображать полный текст сообщения с этим ID.